# HAProxy and Keepalived for rsyslog load balance

Tags: linux, haproxy, rsyslog, keepalived

I want to make use of HAProxy and Keepalived for rsyslog load balancing. Is it possible to install HAProxy and Keepalived on the same host where the rsyslog server is running? Reason being i only have 2 servers and i need to achieve load balancing for rsyslog daemon by using HAProxy and Keepalived. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

yes its no problem. You can use keepalive for vrrp address. Config realserver in keepalive. Realserver are HAproxy IP's (example backend ips). HaProxy send the traffic to localost syslogserver.